# Mutate all dates on getAttributeValue automatically

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to create a sort of global mutator for any date string that is retreived from the database.

Now this is probably the wrong way of going about it (and doesn't even work), but I created a class called `App\Http\Mutators\ModelMutator` which extends `Eloquent\Model`.

I then changed the `Eloquent` alias in `app.php` to point to this new class.

Here is the code for the new class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Mutators;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ModelMutator extends Model
{
    function getAttributeValue($key)
    {
        $value = parent::getAttributeValue($key);

        if (strtotime($value)) {
            $value = tolocal($value);
        }

        return $value;
    }
}
```

This isn't working at all. In fact it appears it isn't even getting called whenever something is retrieved from the database.

I just want to have any date string retrieved from the database to apply the `tolocal` function.

My biggest issue is I am using packages outside of the `App\` namespace and do not want to have to write mutators and modify every single package `extends Model` class.

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent already has this functionality. Use the `$dates` property:

```
protected $dates = [
    'created_at',
    'updated_at',
    'deleted_at'
];
```

> By default, Eloquent will convert the created_at and updated_at columns to instances of Carbon, which extends the PHP DateTime class to provide an assortment of helpful methods. You may customize which dates are automatically mutated, and even completely disable this mutation, by overriding the $dates property of your model

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators

Comment: How would I utilize this for models inside packages I am using without actually modifying the package content itself?

Comment: I found the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33886101/how-to-extend-and-modify-a-vendor-model-in-laravel-5